# Difference between neutral and basic activated alumina

Tags: materials, chromatography, adsorption

Sigma Aldrich [sells](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/content/dam/sigma-aldrich/docs/Sigma-Aldrich/Product_Information_Sheet/a1772pis.pdf) two different types of activated alumina for column chromatography: neutral and basic.

Apparently basic alumina is more active and better at adsorbing anions.

Why is this the case?